# Using Loop in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a doubt regarding MySQL. I have a table where it has some columns. I have to make a calculation to each entry using the entry itself. presently I am kind of using the following way for each entry ...

```
select ((count(b)*10)/sum(a)) as AvgT from Kross where b = 'ABC';
```

Is there anyway to do it for all the entries without using WHERE??? May be using a loop for every entry in the column b or something like that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: [`group by`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-select.html) instead of `where`.

```
select ((count(b)*10)/sum(a)) as AvgT from Kross group by b
```